# Can Quicktime Player Save Recordings as an MP3 by Default?

Tags: audio, quicktime, defaults, mp3

Quicktime Player allows a very nice workflow for recording audio for Google Slides – right up to the point where you try to insert the M4A audio file that comes out of Quicktime Player. Then Google refuses to play nicely and the workflow becomes ugly…

Perhaps it's the smoke out here on the west coast, but my Google foo is failing to find any `defaults` settings that would change the format of the saved file (without having to go back and convert it).

Is there any way to have the default format for audio recordings be MP3 instead of M4A?

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, QuickTime Player doesn't offer a good range of conversion formats. Your best option is either to record the audio in another application, like Sound Studio or Audacity; or post-process the audio file.

Answer (score 0):

FYI: Not sure if this is the solution you are looking for exactly, and forgive me if this is not an appropriate posting, but thought it might be of use to someone out there:

If instead of using the 'save' command, in QuickTime Player, you can select 'export as' from the file menu, and in it's sub-menu, select 'audio only' and it will create an .m4a file, if that helps.

Comment: m4a is not mp3, so this is definitely not an applicable answer.

Answer (score -1):

You could convert it with Music. Apple has written a [guide](https://support.apple.com/en-ae/HT204310) on how to do it.